# Clicking on a radio button invokes a popup which is not recognized by selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I am struck recognizing an popup with a 'OK' button, which is invoked as process of clicking a radio button.

I need to click on 'OK' Button in the popup else the screen is freezes and we can't go any further in the test case.

```
<HTML CODE>
    <td class="req" align="right"> Exposure: </td>
    <td align="left">
    <input type="radio" value="1" onclick="javascript:onClick_exposure_type(this);" name="exposure_type">
    Open
    <input type="radio" value="2" onclick="javascript:onClick_exposure_type(this);" name="exposure_type">
    Closed
    </td>
    <HTML CODE>
```

When i record this event in selenium IDE, I get the following

```
click("xpath=(//input[@name='exposure_type'])[2]")
selectWindow("null")
clickAndWait("name=btnOkay")
```

I tried doing something like this & didnt help

```
executeScript("window.confirm = function(msg){return true;};")
```

Any thoughts would be grateful.

Comment: which language are coding in?

Comment: just give a try with index based window selection.

Comment: What kind of popup? IDE switched to another browser window for a while there. But your solution was targeted for JavaScript's `confirm()`. If the popup is a new browser window, you must [switch to it](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#selectWindow%28java.lang.String%29).